# msdos source code/why we push ss register in stack and after that we pop into ds register

Tags: assembly, x86, push, dos, x86-16

I was going through msdos source code files there I found some amazing assembly instructions
why we push ss register in stack and after that we pop into ds register.

Actually the little bit more code is here:
For more convenience I am writing "save_world" procedure.

```
Start procedure save_world:
    Push ax
    Push bx
    Push cx
    Push dx
    Push si
    Push di
    Push cs
    Push es
    Push ds
    End procedure,

Invoke save_world:
    pop ds
    push ss
    pop es
    push ss
    pop ds
    ASSUME DS:DOSGROUP
```

more code follows. For clarity I want to say that I was going through msdos source code files.

Comment: Hard to tell without more context. It's just setting up `ds` to be the same as `ss` for whatever reason. Note that `mov ds, ss` does not exist, hence going through the stack.

Comment: push/pop are 1 byte each, so this is the most compact way to write it, and doesn't need a temporary register the way `mov ax, ss` / `mov ds, ax` would. IDK why the code you're looking at would repeat the sequence twice, but it's **obviously super weird because it uses `pop cs`!!!**  [`pop cs` isn't supported](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/POP), but might have been on some version of 8086 as an alternative to a `far jmp`.  That's by far the more amazing part of this sequence of instructions.

Comment: This is a repost of [What does PUSH SS / POP DS do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168152/what-does-push-ss-pop-ds-do); I closed that as a duplicate of this.

Comment: @PeterCordes `pop cs` was an undocumented opcode on the original 8086. It used the obvious encoding for it on the opcode table, what is now the 0x0F prefix.

Comment: When you say MSDOS source code, do you mean source for programs that run under DOS, or the actual source *of* the operating system, that DOS itself could be built from?  I tried to fix your lack of code formatting, but I'm not it matches what you were trying to write.

Comment: I have some other assembly language problems.I can not ask separately because this system is restricting me in do so. My problem in assembly language is as follows:DEVICE_READ EQU 4,DEVICE_READ_WRITE_HEADER_LENGTH EQU 22,MOV (DEVICE_READ SHL 8) OR DEVICE_READ_WRITE_HEADER_LENTGH

Answer (score 0):

See comment by Jester. There's no `mov ds, ss` instruction in x86-16. They could have used intermediate register:

```
mov ax, ss
mov ds, ax
```

But either they wanted to save space or did not have registers to spoil.